How to Get Share Name Containing File
Does a means exist, ideally in or from VBA (directly or via Win32, PowerShell, VBS, WMI, or CMD call), to programmatically return / get the first Windows share name containing a fully qualified local file name?
Edit:  To clarify, (a) the relevant share name in virtually all cases will be that of a shared directory/folder, not a shared drive; (b) the relevant share name will be that of the first shared directory/folder encountered in recursing parent directories from the file, not subdirectories of the drive (so Scripting.Drive.ShareName, which does the latter, isn't suitable).
The objective is to provide networked users (for current purposes, on the same local subnet and without Active Directory) with a string permitting them to access the file in question, e.g., something like \\ServerName\ShareName\path\to\FileName.ext
It's easy enough to programmatically obtain both the computer name and the local URI for the file but the share name element has been elusive.  The difficulty is that the programmatically obtainable local URI makes reference only to the local filesystem, beginning with a drive letter, e.g., .DriveLetter:\path\to\FileName.ext, which of course is meaningless to network users.
Note that the share may be of the containing directory or a superdirectory any number of levels higher.
Any thoughts, including general thoughts regarding approach, on whether and how this might be done would be most appreciated.

https://www.devhut.net/determine-the-path-of-a-mapped-drive/

@TimWilliams thanks but Daniel's code gets the path from a drive letter to which the path already has been mapped.  So, e.g., obtaining \foo\bar\path\to\file from Z:\path\to\file where \foo\bar is mapped to Z:.  That is what one would do from a client machine.  I need to go the other direction, i.e., on the server hosting the share (foo), obtain bar (the share name) from Z:\path\to\file where Z isn't a mapped network resource but a locally mounted data partition.

Like https://superuser.com/questions/309223/how-to-display-a-list-of-network-shares-shared-by-a-windows-computer ?

From that second link it seems like the command net share would give you the info you need.

@TimWilliams, yes, although net view \\servername /all returns all shares on the server, not the share for a particular path.

Well you will need to figure that out from the output…

@TimWilliams LOL.  With no capacity for positional parameters (as with Bash) that I'm aware of, and no output information concerning any element of the shared resource.  Easy peasy!

Please, try the next function:
Function MappedWBFullPath(wb As Workbook) As String
 If Len(wb.Path) > 2 _
     Then MappedWBFullPath = """" & wb.Name & """ is not on a mapped drive...": Exit Function
  With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     MappedWBFullPath = .GetDrive(wb.Path).ShareName
  End With
End Function

You can test it opening an workbook from such a mapped drive and activate it. Then run the next testing Sub:
Sub testMappedWBFullPath()
  Debug.Print MappedWBFullPath(ActiveWorkbook)
  Debug.Print MappedWBFullPath(ThisWorkbook)
  Debug.Print "Worbook network full name: " & MappedWBFullPath(ActiveWorkbook) & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I think the OP wants to do the opposite of this - on the server where the share is located, not on a connected client.  Eg if on server SERVER001 the folder C:\Temp\Blah is shared as MyShare they want to translate something like C:\Temp\Blah\SubFolder\Test.xlsx into \\SERVER001\MyShare\SubFolder\Test.xlsx

@Tim Williams But, this is what the above solution does, I think... I understood from DriveLetter:\path\to\FileName.ext that the respective path is something as X:\Test.xlsx, where X is a mapped location, which is specific to computer where the mapping exists. And the code does exactly what I understood it is necessary. It extracts the mapped location path to be used by everybody connected to that network. Something like \\ServerX\MyFolder1\MyFolder2 concatenated with the file name, if necessary. What do you mean by "the opposite"? I cannot understand your example...

I thought the OP was saying they're not working with a mapped drive, but directly on the server's C drive for example, so there is no mapped drive on their side, only a local path which they want to map to a "share" path of the type \\Servername\Sharename, by looking at the shares configured on the local machine and finding one which contains the file they want to share the path for.

@Tim Williams But a shared folder on the same network can be accessed exactly in the same way by everybody connected to the respective network. Only a mapped location is specific to a single computer... Am I still missing anything? I may admit that English is not my best point...

I guess the OP is on the server and not using the "share" path but is using the local path?  I agree it's not a huge pain to manually make the change, unless the server has dozens of shares...

@FaneDuru, thanks.  I had to translate that a bit from Excel to Access but that's basically the idea.  Unfortunately, the Scripting approach is valid only if the drive (i.e., partition root) is shared, not when a directory / folder is shared because while the Drive.ShareName property exists, rather inexplicably, no corresponding Folder.ShareName property exists.

All:  I was chasing this down and haven't been on top of the comments but to clarify, the programmatically obtainable path is the (full) local path, which I need to translate into a share path.  The computer name also is obtainable, so the missing piece is the share name.  The Scripting approach @FaneDuru recommended can work for a drive but won't for a folder because the latter object has no ShareName property.  I basically need to recurse parent directories until I reach a share, then get its name.

All:  More specifically, in the case of an Access back-end, DAO.TableDef.Connect returns a string from which the full local path to the back end (data) file can be parsed.  This path will vary between the development and production environments.  If a new front end (application) file can be run first on the back end server, and if the share name of the back end file then can be obtained, then copies of the front end file can be distributed to users without having to configure each of those copies individually.

Here's an example using WMI:
Function Tester()
    Debug.Print SharePath("C:\Temp\VBA\text.xlsx")
End Function

Function SharePath(localPath As String) As String
    
    Dim strComputer, objWMIService As Object, colItems As Object, itm
    Dim rv As String, sName, sPath, sServer, maxlen As Long, p
    
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") ' .=local pc
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Share")
    
    For Each itm In colItems     'loop over shares
        p = itm.path
        If Right(p, 1) <> "\" Then p = p & "\" 'ensure ending backslash
        Debug.Print "Name: " & itm.Name, "Path: " & p
        If InStr(1, localPath, p, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            If Len(p) > maxlen Then 'want the longest shared path
                sName = itm.Name
                sPath = p
                sServer = itm.path_.server
                maxlen = Len(p)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If maxlen > 0 Then  'got a match?
        'construct the path
        SharePath = "\\" & sServer & "\" & sName & "\" & _
                    Replace(localPath, sPath, "", compare:=vbTextCompare)
    End If
End Function

You just need to check itm.path to see which of them covers the most of the beginning of your local path and then create the "share" path from that.

thanks.  I'll need to pick this up again tomorrow but pending that, walk me through the GetObject() call.  I'm guessing \. means the current machine, and \root\cimv2 is the default WMI namespace.  What exactly is winmgmts: , and which object has an ExecQuery method?

I really don't know much about WMI - only as much as I google when I need to know something specific. If you really want the details then search for "WMI vbscript".  It's definitely an oldish appraoch (pre-powershell) and a lot of the examples you'll find will be VBscript.

That's about where I am.  Other fire drills, will revert.
